# Problema con las rutas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Soy nuevo en el mundo del framework Laravel y tengo problemas en las rutas, cabe destacar que estoy usando Wampserver y php en su version 7.2.10
les adjunto estas imagenes. ante mano muchas gracias

**Esto es cuando ejecuta la primera ruta (La que viene por default, no estoy retornando una vista, solo un texto)**
[image]

**Y esto es la segunda ruta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: he replicado tu ejercicio sin problemas, veamos si no es un detalle de caché, ejecuta: `php artisan cache:clear` y posterior `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: gracias por el tiempo, pero me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ok @Aldair B.S. si tengo otro aporte te lo dejo aquí

Comment: Estás seguro que la reescritura de URLs está habilitada en tu servidor?

Comment: Estoy usando apache, y si esta habilitada

Comment: Creo que el problema es el modo en el que estás accediendo a la ruta. ¿Por qué necesitas acceder a la raíz incluyendo la ruta al proyecto (`localhost/hellolaravel/public/`) en vez de utilizar un puerto (`localhost:8000/`)?

Comment: ¿qué pasa si defines otra ruta cualquiera? por ejemplo /prueba

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por sus aportes, ya solucione el incidente